# How to bind an SSL certificate to a particular port on IIS?

Tags: iis, https, ssl-certificate

I have code on my website to make an HTTP request to my own server at port 8070. In that port, a nodejs server is listening for requests. Because of this unsecured port, the request gets blocked by the browser. How can I bind this port to an SSL certificate in order to facilitate this request?

Comment: The common practice is to create an HTTPS site on IIS, and then set up reverse proxy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing to forward traffic to your node server at port 8070.

Comment: @LexLi Thank you. I got that idea. Can u please elaborate a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lex Li says you could use IIS url rewrtie to achieve your requirement.

You could firstly create a IIS application with the certificate. Then you could install the url rewrite extension by using this [url](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

Then you could open the web.config and add below config setting:

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8070/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 2):

Select your site -> Bindings -> Add HTTPS binding (you will need a certificate installed)

[image]

Comment: I have tried this. But it doesn't work for me. Because I have to run a node server on that port. I can't run node server when I bind port from here.